# Joomla categories stay on my website after moving them to trash

Tags: php, joomla

I got a basic joomla cms (only the core cms) with some content pages linked to it and a dynamic menu.

If I delete an article it deletes it from the site now too, due to this code I added:

```
"SELECT * FROM `lb_content` WHERE catid = '".$sub['id']."' AND state = 1 order by ordering"
```

So it only shows items with state = 1. The same should go for categories, only in joomla their status is set within `published`.

So I added this:

```
"SELECT * FROM `lb_categories` WHERE parent_id = '".$menu['id']."' AND published = 1 order by rgt ASC"
```

Yet after moving a category to trash, it still shows on my site. Does anyone know why that is?

Comment: Never delete like this, always use the API. Further there is a difference between putting it in the trash and deleting.

Comment: @Elin For this case this was needed, I know it's not ideal.

Comment: No really, the tree is going to be messed up also you have to make sure that all of the content items are deleted and also you need to deal with the assets table which is now going to be corrupted.

Comment: @Elin I use a barebone joomla database, so there is no actual joomla being used except for the cms design.

Comment: Well just understand that the ACL depends on that and also your queries will come to a crawl when the assets table and the data referenced in it get out of synch.

Comment: @Elin What do you mean with ACL?

Comment: Access Control Lists meaning who can and cannot access, edit, delete etc  each item in a category or each category.